# What is the structure constant in layman's?

Tags: lie-algebra, yang-mills

In the Yang-Mills field strength tensor, there's this symbol *f* which is the structure constant. What is the definition of this structure constant in layman's terms?

Comment: Both people telling you that $SU(3)$ is the only gauge group "Yang-Mills theory" can have are wrong.

Comment: Yang-Mills theory can be formulated for general SU(N), but I think SU(3) is a good specific example since it comes up in particle physics commonly.

Comment: @klippo As far as I know, any Lie group will do. Remember the surfer dude with the $E _8$ theory?

Answer (score 2):

In the Yang-Mills theory describing QCD, the underlying symmetry group is the Lie group SU(3). The Lie algebra of a given Lie group is characterized by how the generators of the group commute. The commutation relations for the generators of a Lie group can be written as linear combinations of the other generators, with coefficients of this linear combination being called "structure constants".

For the group SU(3), the generators are $T^a = \frac{\lambda^a}{2}$, where the $\lambda^a$'s are the 8 Gell-Mann matrices. The commutation relations of these generators are given by $$[T^a, T^b] = i f^{abc}T^c,$$ where $f^{abc}$ is the totally antisymmetric symbol defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants).

Edit: In layman's terms, the structure constants are unique to a specific Lie group (continuous group). They contain valuable information about how the group's generators behave.

Comment: In the wikipedia, it says that the structure constant corresponds to particles? What does that mean?

Comment: In the wikipedia article it says actually that the basis vectors of a Lie algebra (which are the generators, not the structure constants) can correspond to particles.  This is true in the sense that, for example, the sigma matrices, which are the generators of the SU(2) group, can represent spin operators for a particle. The structure constants of SU(2) then tell you how the sigma matrices commute with each other.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear to a layperson. I have another question which may be stupid. Like the derivatives in the kinetic term of the field strength tensor, does the structure constant describe the potential energy of the field?

Comment: I think that the best interpretation would be that nonzero f^abc permits terms representing self-interaction of the gauge vector field A_mu. I think this makes sense because the gluon has self-interaction vertices. A term like this is not present in QED since the photon cannot self-interact.

Comment: @Crinoid *Thanks for making it clear to a layperson.* I’m confused. You are a “layperson” who understands what Lie groups, Lie algebras, generators, commutation relations, matrices, and totally antisymmetric symbols are? To me, a layperson knows none of this mathematics.

Comment: Now, I am as well. If you are indeed more or less familiar with those concepts, I could undelete my answer, edit it accordingly and rephrase it a bit simpler. (Otherwise I could not say any more than @klippo did here, which is also why I went more into Lie theory in the first place.) (@Ghoster: And thanks for your feedback, I really appreciate not being left confused.)

Comment: I suggest starting your answer with “In the Yang-Mills theory describing quantum chromodynamics…” As is, your answer seems misleading to me.

Comment: Thanks that's a good suggestion. I'm a bit narrow-minded as I study particle physics so I didn't consider other possibilities.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz I’m sorry now that I considered your answer inappropriate for a layperson, since the OP apparently is not a layperson. Unfortunately, if you bring it back I think it’s too late to reverse my downvote. But if you edit it a bit, I think the system will let me.

Comment: @Ghoster I am indeed a layperson, I don't entirely know these Lie groups, commutators, etc.

Comment: @klippo added another answer (in layman's), which I'm able to understand a bit of what f^abc mean

Answer (score 2):

The structure constants are linear coefficients.

Consider a vector space $V$ with a basis $(\lambda_i)_{i\in I}$. If an additional bilinear operation $V\times V\rightarrow V$ is given on $V$, it is called *algebra* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field)) or *Lie algebra* (see [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+algebra) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)) depending on what additional conditions this bilinear operation fulfills. Lie algebras, whose bilinear operation is also called *commutator*, are very important for physics, especially quantum theory.

To fully describe the commutator, we only need to know the result of it being applied to pairs of basis vectors $(\lambda_i)_{i\in I}$ because of bilinearity. To get the structure constants, we then express the result as a linear combination using the basis vectors again:
$$[\lambda_a,\lambda_b]
=2if_{ab}^c\lambda_c.$$
You can compare this to the *angular momentum algebra* given by $[L_i,L_j]=\varepsilon_{ijk}L_k$. (A smiliar approach can also be found in other areas of mathematics and physics, the *Christoffel symbols* $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ are also linear coefficients for example.) In case of Yang-Mills theories, the Lie algebra considered is called the *special unitary Lie algebra* and defined as:
$$\mathfrak{su}(n)
:=\left\{A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}|A^H=-A,\operatorname{tr}(A)=0\right\}.$$
For $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, a suitable basis are the three ($2^2-1$) [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). For $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, a suitable basis are the eight ($3^2-1$) [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices). This is the Lie algebra used in *quantum chromodynamic*, every basis vector (also called generator) corresponds to one of the eight quarks.

Comment: It’s not wrong. The OP asked for an answer “in laymen’s terms” and a layman could not understand this. I think the sophistication of answers should be scaled to the sophistication of the questioner.

Comment: @Ghoster: After reading your comment under the answer above, I now revisited my answer to make it fully understandable for a layperson.

Comment: I was able to change my downvote to an upvote.